# Having an issue with centering images and keep it responsive for all devices

Tags: html, css

I have an image with 955x955. I want it responsive for all devices. The image is square size but the section is not the square size that's why when I visit my website on a small screen, it did not look good. And my focus of this image is "the man". I want to keep the man center, it doesn't matter which device I use for visiting my website. I want this image like the right one.
[image]

And the code is

```css
img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: Try to resize it with % or rem

Comment: Where's the code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to show us your code including the actual image because the positioning required will depend on the positioning of the man within the image (vertically as well as horizontally).

Comment: this is the code,  img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
object-fit:cover;
}

Comment: You could try having the image as a background in it's Div. Then use `background: url(path-to-your-image) 50% 50% no-repeat`. You may also have to add `background-size: cover` but try it first without that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give class name as responsive to your image field and in media, query add the below code

```
 .responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I try this one  .responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} but didn't work

Comment: How you applied this code .. paste your code here for more clarification.

Comment: actually, I'm using bootstrap and also add this code for get perfect shape of image in every single device. img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
object-fit:cover;
}

Comment: Add this code in media query , it will works.. media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .img{
    Max-width:100%; height:auto;
  }
}